# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 59,Token in error = usage ]

Tags: c#

When i insert data in table it give me error

```
public int SolveSection(string sectionName, string userid, string examId, string TotalSolveQuestion, string time)
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
    int a = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    _connection.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@User_id", userid));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Exame_id", examId));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Interactive usage of English_Solve_Total_qouation", TotalSolveQuestion));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Interactive usage of EnglishT", time));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Interactive usage of English", sectionName));

    cmd.Connection = _connection;
    //cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Personal_information_ofcandidat](User_id,Name,MName,LName,Exam_date,Exam_id,College_Name,Email_id,Phone_no) values('" + userid + "','" + uname + "','" + muname + "','" + luname + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + examid + "','" + collegname + "','" + email + "','" + mobile + "')";

    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Solve_Question](user_id,Exame_id,Interactive usage of English_Solve_Total_qouation,Interactive usage of EnglishT,Interactive usage of English)" + "values(@User_id,@Exame_id,@Interactive usage of English_Solve_Total_qouation,@Interactive usage of EnglishT,@Interactive usage of English)";

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    try
    {
        a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (a > 0)
        {  
        }
        else { userid = ""; }
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ee) { }

    return a;
}
```

It gives me an error message:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 59,Token in error = usage ]
>    at line ExecuteNonQuery() line. Where I Wrong.

Comment: [Column with a space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove spaces from the column name and from the parameters name and if you want column names with space then put them into `[column Name]`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@User_id", userid));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Exame_id", examId));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Interactive_usage_of_English_Solve_Total_qouation", TotalSolveQuestion));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Interactive_usage_of_EnglishT", time));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Interactive_usage_of_English", sectionName));

cmd.Connection = _connection;
//cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Personal_information_ofcandidat](User_id,Name,MName,LName,Exam_date,Exam_id,College_Name,Email_id,Phone_no) values('" + userid + "','" + uname + "','" + muname + "','" + luname + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + examid + "','" + collegname + "','" + email + "','" + mobile + "')";

cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Solve_Question] (user_id,Exame_id,[Interactive usage of English_Solve_Total_qouation],[Interactive usage of EnglishT],[Interactive usage of English])" + "values (@User_id,@Exame_id,@Interactive_usage_of_English_Solve_Total_qouation, @Interactive_usage_of_EnglishT,@Interactive_usage_of_English)";
```